# Apply changes using TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates

Tags: delphi, datasnap, firedac

I have this code from a tutorial from Embarcadero to pass dataset as JSON:

```
procedure TServerMethods1.ApplyChangesDepartmentEmployees( const ADeltaList: TFDJSONDeltas); 
var LApply: TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates; 
begin 

TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates.Create(ADeltaList); 
LApply.ApplyUpdates('Departement', FDQueryDepartment.Command); 

if LApply.Errors.Count = 0 then 
  LApply.ApplyUpdates('Emplyees', FDQueryDepartmentEmployees.Command); 

if LApply.Errors.Count > 0 then 
  Exception.Create(LApply.Errors.Strings.Text); 
end;
```

But I have some questions about the code:

What is `TFDJSONDeltas` ? and what Deltas mean ?

Why I have to create `TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates` ?

What `ApplyUpdates` do and what is its syntax ?

This all I got from documentation: 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Data.FireDACJSONReflect.TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very old question but thought of answering.

JSON Delta is a differential JSON which can be patched to an existing JSON string.

It is helpful for mobile applications where Data connection may not be consistent.

`ApplyUpdates` applies a `DataTable in SQL` using the `JSONDelta`.

**Syntax**:

```
LApply.ApplyUpdates('table_name', 'query.Command');
```